# TLF shoots error when used inside a SWC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, swc, tlf

simple issue here.
I created a SWC which is a simple MovieClip that contains some TLF text fields.
I have embedded the font using the Flash Professional IDE.
When instance this Class in my main app

```
 var myInstance:MovieClip = new SomeClass() as MovieClip
```

I get a Type Coercion error call:

```
Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::MovieClip@1fbcc271 to fl.text.TCMText.
```

Any Ideas why and how can solve it?

Vivo.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into a known error in Flash with TLF texts and loaded SWFs, [you can read a long discussion about this problem here](http://www.stevensacks.net/2010/05/28/flash-cs5-tlf-engine-causes-errors-with-loaded-swfs/).

Adobe released a while ago [this article providing two different possible fixes](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/838/cpsid_83812.html), I think in your case only the first one applies since you are trying putting your stuff in a SWC and not loading a SWF. What you should do is change the default linkage for the TLF SWC to **merged into code** in your loaded SWC, and make sure to follow all steps in the article for good measure.